# Create PDF file with byte array and download/save it

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have an AJAX function who call a server side method, and this method call an API and it return a byte array. I want to convert this byte array in a PDF file, and then download the file. I have this code:

AJAX function:

```
function ObtenerF(nroF) {
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/De.aspx/BuscarFVW',
        data: JSON.stringify({ nF: nroF }),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (msg) {
            debugger;
            if (msg.d != null) {
                window.open();
            }
        },
        error: function () {
        }
    });
}
```

Code behind method:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static byte[] BuscarFVW(string nF)
{
     var respuesta = new Serv.L.SeL((U)HttpContext.Current.Session["UT"]).ObtenerF(nF);
     if (respuesta != null)
     {
         File.WriteAllBytes(@"~\Content\tmp\hello.pdf", respuesta.F);
         return respuesta.F;
     }
     else
         return null;
}
```

I try this in the BuscarFVW method, but I can't pass a relative path as parameter in File.WriteAllBytes, and I don't know how to automatically download the new PDF file or save in the tmp folder in the project, and open a new tab with the PDF file (I can make this with an absolute path but this don't gonna work if I public the project in another server, but this work in my local with a path like C:/User/Desktop).

Any suggestion? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use ajax to download PDF and it's a bad habit to do so.
use can directly use a tag to download the file or iframe tag to present it.

And you can use window.location = '[your rout]';
to download the file.